# Operator Overloading C++

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I found this code on internet :

```
Class Book{
Public:
void operator()(int Counter) const throw();
}
```

My question is, what operator overloading the above code used?

Comment: Overloading the parenthesis operator ()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Firstly, that code is wrong; since C++ is case sensitive, `Class` and `Public` are not keywords. It is also very unusual (albeit legal) to capitalize the first letter of a parameter name (`Counter`).

Assuming correct capitalization, what you have is an overload of the function-call operator. It allows you to "call" an instance of `Book` as if it was a function:

```
Book b;
...
b(23);
```

Answer (score 2):

The above class is basically called a "Functor". It has an overloaded "()" operator. Widely used in STL Algorithms.